# Make modules talk to eachother

Tags: puppet

I'm currently working on a profile to lock down a server by making sure services and users are disabled. For example, Apache.

This gives issues when another profile wants to manage the resource, because then I will have two Service[apache] resources.

Now I could use something like define, but my prefered method would be some way the profile::apache could talk to profile::lockdown and tell it to leave apache alone.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you need to use hiera for archive what you want.

```
class profiles::apache {
  class { '::apache': }
}
```

Now if my class `profiles::apache` is begin used for 1000 nodes and I want to stop the service in one particular server, in hiera I can use something like this.

hiera 3 configuration example hiera.yaml

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
  - json
:yaml:
  :datadir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{::environment}/hieradata"
:json:
  :datadir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{::environment}/hieradata"
:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "virtual/%{::virtual}"
  - "common"
```

Now in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/nodes/servername.domain.local.yaml` insert this `apache::service_ensure: stopped`

With hiera you can manipulate the parameter of the classes by nodes or something else